# Comparing two arrays with field in common then pushing to a new array with corresponding grouped fields

Tags: javascript, node.js

general programming problem here.

I have this array called `SPACES`

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69,
    challengers: [
      5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226,
      5dfa26f46719311869ac1756,
      5dfa270c6719311869ac1757
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81,
    challengers: [ 5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226, 5dfa26f46719311869ac1756 ],
  }
]
```

And this array called `USERS`

```
[
  {
    _id: 5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226,
    name: 'Account 1',
    email: 'account1@gmail.com',
    spaces: [ 5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69, 5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81 ],
  },
  {
    _id: 5dfa26f46719311869ac1756,
    name: 'Account 2',
    email: 'account2@gmail.com',
    spaces: [ 5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69, 5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81 ]
  },
  {
    _id: 5dfa270c6719311869ac1757,
    name: 'Account 3',
    email: 'account3@gmail.com',
    spaces: [ 5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69 ]
  }
]
```

What I want to do, is go through both, and instead of having the `SPACES.challengers` array be just `IDS`, I would like the array to contain each `USER` object.

So for example, if the `USER` has an ID that is inside the `SPACES.challengers` array, then push the user into that array (which will then be the entire object).

SO FAR I have tried this (I am not very good yet):

```
 users.map( ( user ) => {
          spaces.map( ( space ) => {
              if ( user.spaces.includes( space._id ) ) {
                       space.challengers.push(user)
                  }
             } );
        } );
```

However, I am not getting inside the IF block. (Even if I did, not sure if it would work OR if this is even how to do it). It feels Odd doing double maps, as I get so many iterations, and it duplicates my push (cause I have no logic to see if it just has been pushed).

Comment: Is every entry in the `Users` array has a unique ID? If yes, a hashmap can be built out of this array to search easily (and faster) for an `ID` while looping through `challengers` array inside `Spaces` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map` and `.find` should work here. keep it simple.

```js
var spaces = [
    {
      _id: "5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69",
      challengers: [
        "5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226",
        "5dfa26f46719311869ac1756",
        "5dfa270c6719311869ac1757"
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: "5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81",
      challengers: ["5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226", "5dfa26f46719311869ac1756", "some non existent"]
    }
  ],
  users = [
    {
      _id: "5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226",
      name: "Account 1",
      email: "account1@gmail.com",
      spaces: ["5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69", "5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81"]
    },
    {
      _id: "5dfa26f46719311869ac1756",
      name: "Account 2",
      email: "account2@gmail.com",
      spaces: ["5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69", "5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81"]
    },
    {
      _id: "5dfa270c6719311869ac1757",
      name: "Account 3",
      email: "account3@gmail.com",
      spaces: ["5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69"]
    }
  ],
  result = spaces.map(({ _id, challengers }) => ({
    _id,
    challengers: challengers.map(challenger =>
      users.find(user => user._id === challenger)
    ).filter(row => row)
  }));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: This returns the challenger array as undefined items (in the result variable)

Comment: you will need to do some null checks if some ids doesn't exist

Comment: I did that, and when consoling something, I get the correct result. When returning user, still get undefined. 

```
result = spaces.map( ( { _id, challengers } ) => ({
    _id,
    challengers: challengers.map( challenger => {
        users.find( ( user ) => {
            if ( user._id === challenger ) {
                return user;
            }
        } );
    } )
}) );
@Ashish Modi

Comment: @CevinThomas I have added a non existent id in input and handled that using filter. updated the code. see if that helps.

Comment: filters out the null of undefined. `filter(row => row)` id equal to `if(row)` which basically filter out null or undefined values

Comment: if you check [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) polyfill, you will find that it is iterating over the array, this will increase complexity to ~O(n^3).

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** every entry in the `Users` array has a unique ID, we can build a `Hashmap` to store `(id, index)` pairs in order to search efficiently for an ID from `Users` array while looping through `Spaces` array.

```js
let spaces = [{_id: '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69',challengers: ['5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226', '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756', '5dfa270c6719311869ac1757']},{_id: '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81',challengers: [ '5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226', '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756' ],}]

let users = [{_id: '5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226',name: 'Account 1',email: 'account1@gmail.com',spaces: [ '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69', '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81' ],},{_id: '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756',name: 'Account 2',email: 'account2@gmail.com',spaces: [ '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69', '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81' ]},{_id: '5dfa270c6719311869ac1757',name: 'Account 3',email: 'account3@gmail.com',spaces: [ '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69' ]}]

let IDIndexMapping = {} // To store (_id, index) pairs, in order to improve search efficiency

for(let index in users) // Iterate through Users array using index
    IDIndexMapping[users[index]._id] = index; // store (_id, index) pair in IDIndexMapping

// I'm avoiding using `map` and using vanilla `for` loop for space efficiency
// as map returns a new array but with `for` loop, we can perform changes in-place

for(let outerIndex in spaces){ // Iterate through `spaces` array using index
    let challengers = spaces[outerIndex].challengers; // Get challengers array
    for(let innerIndex in challengers){ // Iterate through challengers array using index
        let ID = challengers[innerIndex]; // Get ID
        if(ID in IDIndexMapping) // If ID exists in IDIndexMapping
            spaces[outerIndex].challengers[innerIndex] = users[IDIndexMapping[ID]]; // Change ID to actual User object
    }
}
console.log(spaces)
```

---

Output

```js
[ { _id: '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69',
    challengers: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81',
    challengers: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map of challengers for look-up and then put them in spaces.

//create user map for look-up

```
userMap = users.reduce((res, val) => ({
  ...res,
  [val._id]: val
}), {});
```

//change challenger id with user object

```
inflatedSpaces = spaces.map(s => ({ ...s, challengers: s.challengers.map(c => userMap[c]) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the users with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Beside the destructuring of the object for mapping this answer uses for this part

```
challengers: challengers.map(
    Map.prototype.get,                  // cb with a prototype and using `this`
    new Map(users.map(o => [o._id, o])) // thisArg
)
```

the above mentioned `Map` in two parts.

The lower part generates an instance of `Map` where `_id` of the users items is used as key and the whole object as value. This instance is uses as `thisArg` of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the second parameter.

The upper part is a prototype of `Map`, used as callback. And while an `this` object is supplied, a binding ([`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) is not necessary.

```js
var spaces = [{ _id: '5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69', challengers: ['5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226', '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756', '5dfa270c6719311869ac1757'] }, { _id: '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81', challengers: ['5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226', '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756'] }],
    users = [{ _id: '5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226', name: 'Account 1', email: 'account1@gmail.com', spaces: ['5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69', '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81'] }, { _id: '5dfa26f46719311869ac1756', name: 'Account 2', email: 'account2@gmail.com', spaces: ['5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69', '5e1c4eb9c9461510407d5e81'] },{ _id: '5dfa270c6719311869ac1757', name: 'Account 3', email: 'account3@gmail.com', spaces: ['5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69'] }],
    result = spaces.map(({ _id, challengers }) => ({
        _id,
        challengers: challengers.map(
            Map.prototype.get,
            new Map(users.map(o => [o._id, o]))
        )
    }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Looks very interesting, could you walk me through a little bit of the thought process behind the code and what it does? I have yet to see a complex map manoeuvre like this. Thank you!